# how to format String to Date with format dd-mm-yyyy in java

Tags: java, date, java-time

I need some support. I desired convert a variable String to Date. The variable Date should be format dd-MM-yyyy.

```
 import java.util.Date;
    ....
    ...
    String a = "2022-05-12";
    Date b; // should be dd-MM-yyyy 
    
    do some to format...
    
    return b; // return b with format dd-MM-yyyy, remember this variable is type Date no String
```

I was trying to do something but the format obtained is not the desired one.

[image]

Comment: When you want to print a `Date`, you need to format it again. You can have a look at the implementation of the `toString` method. If your are only interested in the days, [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) might be a good pick.

Comment: a `Date` has only a one format when using its `toString`  method - that format cannot be changed - a formatter must be used to `format` it into a string. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `Date` represents an instant in time, not a date. It's very unfortunately named. You should be using `java.time.LocalDate`, or `java.time.ZonedDateTime`, or similar. None of those represent a format. To 'print' such an object with a specific format, pass it to a formatter which gives you a string.

Comment: 1. Don't use `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date`, they are out-of-date, use the `java.time.*` APIs instead; 2. Dates (in general) are simply containers for the amount of time which has passed since a given point in time (ie the Unix epoch), they don't, by design, have a concept of "format", the `toString` implementation is simply there to provide information, this is what formatters are used for, you format the date/time object to a `String`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse( "2022-05-12" )
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" )
)
```

> 12-05-2022

## *java.time*

Use modern *java.time* classes. Never use the terrible `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` classes.

## ISO 8601

Your input conforms to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format used by default in the *java.time* classes for parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `LocalDate`

Parse your date-only input as a date-only object, a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
String input = "2022-05-12" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
```

To generate text in your desired format, specify a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

Rather than hardcode a particular pattern, I suggest learning to automatically localize using [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate(java.time.format.FormatStyle)).

All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Always search thoroughly before posting. Search to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is converting from string to date. It seems that you want it to PRINT the date in a specific format.

Where is an example of how to do it:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2022/05/18 00:18:43
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I mean I gave an example of the stuff he is working with. You don't really know which jdk he is using.

Comment: The *java.time* classes are built into every version of Java not past End-Of-Life, Java 8 through Java 18. For those stuck on Java 6 or 7, most of the *java.time* functionality is available in the *ThreeTen-Backport* library. There really is no need to be using those terrible legacy classes.